# What is the name of this thing? (hex key reduction?)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, tools

What is the name of this thing?

I am trying to find it by keywords like "hex hey reduction" etc. but so far no results. My problem is that the plastic socket is easily damaged and I want to find a similar item, but made from metal only.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another name you might find it is [Hex bit adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex+bit+adapter&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjxgOny9ZXsAhUJ2aQKHbRtAB0Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=hex+bit+adapter&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAAyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgQIABAYOgQIIxAnOggIABAIEAcQHlDFhDVY0KA1YJ2iNWgBcAB4AYABwQaIAecVkgENMC40LjIuMS4wLjEuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=lB53X_HmEYmykwW024HoAQ&bih=578&biw=1280&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGR775GR775).

or [Hex Shank Socket Nut Driver Set Drill Bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hex+Shank+Socket+Magnetic+Nut+Driver+Set+Drill+Bit&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGR775GR775&sxsrf=ALeKk00nhCZsdhRJDniajE7UdHpKRu52wQ:1601644250888&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjaq4Xl_ZXsAhWoM-wKHTyjBVcQ_AUoAXoECBYQAw&biw=1280&bih=578&dpr=1.5)

[Amazon has a nice set that you might like](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F7DDLHI)

Answer (score 1):

Male to female hex adapter would be what I would start with, then start adding in dimensions.